# MySQL groupby in stages

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like this (shown without any grouping) and am using MySQL 5.5.

```
mytable
================================================================================
id    type     parent_type     type_id     content                     parent_id
================================================================================
1     type1    NULL            3           john's test content         NULL
2     type1    NULL            3           hi there, this is john      NULL
3     type2    ptype1          4           john@gmail.com              2
4     type3    ptype1          2           John Smith                  2
5     type3    ptype1          8           Sean John John              10
6     type3    ptype1          13          John Smith                  11
```

I would like to group all the rows first by by `parent_type` and `parent_id` then `type` and `type_id`. `Parent_type` and `parent_id` can be some times `NULL`, but `NULLs` should not be grouped.

Here's what I am trying at the moment:

```
SELECT id, type, IFNULL(parent_type, UUID()) as parent_type, type_id, content, IFNULL(parent_id, UUID()) as parent_id
FROM mytable
WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST('john*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP BY parent_type, parent_id, type_index, type_id LIMIT 10 ;
```

But the desired result is, I want the result to be grouped by `parent_type` and `parent_id` first, and then grouped by `parent_type` and `parent_id` like so:

```
mytable
================================================================================
id    type     parent_type     type_id     content                     parent_id
================================================================================
1     type1    NULL            3           john's test content         NULL
3     type2    ptype1          4           john@gmail.com              2
5     type3    ptype1          8           Sean John John              10
6     type3    ptype1          13          John Smith                  11
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Rows 3 and 4 don't have the same type_ids.

Comment: Ahh I see. Is there a way to group by parent_type and parent_id first, then group by type and type_id on the result?

Comment: @Jason_vorhees: I would prefer to do it all in one query as opposed to selecting into a temp table, then selecting out of that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you can post the sample results you're looking for from the sample data provided.

Comment: @phpdev one advice you can use new column as group_no and then do this two querry to assign them in same group

Comment: Question edited with the result I would am trying to get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a subquery did the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT id, type, type_id, content, MATCH(content) AGAINST('john') as relevance, IFNULL(parent_type, UUID()) as parent_type, IFNULL(parent_id, UUID()) as parent_id
     FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST('john*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP BY parent_type, parent_id
) as search
GROUP BY search.type, search.type_id DESC  LIMIT 10 ;
```